# Map Fragment doesn't load with same GPS location and Map Type

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm new to Android programming. I'm working on an Android project where I need to access Google Maps. I've a navigation drawer with couple of options which include Google Map Location too.

So whenever I try to load the map first time it works fine and loads the map with current GPS location and with the MAP TYPE defined.

> But whenever I try to switch to other fragment and come back to Map
>   fragment, the GPS function and Map Type doesn't work.

Help is needed. Thanks in advance. I'm trying my possible to fix it. :)

My code is below.

> What I'm trying to do here is whenever a user touches somewhere, a
>   marker will be placed on that location.

```
 public class AddCustomerLocationFragment extends Fragment implements
        LocationListener {

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private Marker marker;
    private boolean markerAvailable;
    private Bundle bundle;
    Button btnReset, btnSetLocation;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private View view;
    private double[] addCustomerLocation = new double[10];

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addcustomer_location,
     container, false);
     MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
     mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
     btnReset = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
     btnSetLocation = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSetLocation);
     mapView.onCreate(bundle);
     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
     .getSystemService(
     Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
     getGPS();
     } else {
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
     LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);
     }
     map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
     map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
     map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

     map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
     public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
     Toast.makeText(
     getActivity(),
     "Latitude:" + point.latitude + ", Longitude:"
     + point.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     addMarker(point);
     markerAvailable = true;
     }
     });
     btnSetLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(
     getActivity(),
     "Your current loaction is set to: Latitude:"
     + addCustomerLocation[0] + ", Longitude:"
     + addCustomerLocation[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
     .show();

     }
     });
     btnReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     marker.remove();
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker is Reset",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     markerAvailable = false;
     }
     });

     // add a marker
     //
     return v;
     }
    private void getGPS() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        onLocationChanged(locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bundle = savedInstanceState;
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
        getGPS();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    private void outGPS() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    // @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng latLng = null;
        if (!markerAvailable) {
            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    latLng, 18f);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            addMarker(latLng);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void addMarker(LatLng point) {
        map.clear();
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title(
                "Your Location!?"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: When I switch from map fragment to another fragment and come back to map fragment, the map doesn't load in HYBRID type, neither does it have a default GPS location which I have defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to display a Google Map within a Fragment. I've put onLongClickListeners to place markers on the map, you can change that to onClick.

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();

        setUpMap();
        addingMarkers();
        addingCircles();
        setOnLongClickListenerForAddingNewMarkers();
        return v;
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        // To show my location button on Google maps
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = MainActivity.locationManager;
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        final Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

    }

    private void addingMarkers() {
        // Adding marker to locations - This is a marker for Shipra Mall, which is close to my house. Zoom out to see the Marker
        double latitude = 28.6322269;
        double longitude = 77.3671697;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Shipra Mall");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        // End - Adding marker to location


        // Another marker for District Center in Janakpuri
        double latitude2 = 28.6292303;
        double longitude2 = 77.0805496;

        MarkerOptions marker2 = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2)).title("District Center");
        marker2.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker2);
        // End - Another marker for District Center in Janakpuri
    }

    private void addingCircles() {
        // Latitude and Longitude of Pacific Mall Subash Nagar
        double latitude = 28.6438947;
        double longitude = 77.1128296;

        // Adding a circle around Pacific Mall of 1000 meters radius.
        googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)) // Setting center point
                .radius(1000) // In meters
                .strokeColor(Color.RED) // Color of Border of Circle
                .fillColor(R.color.semi_blue) // Colour of fill, I've set the color to semi transparent blue which I've defined in colors.xml. For fill colour always use semi transparent colour.
                .strokeWidth(10)); // Width of red border.
    }

    private void setOnLongClickListenerForAddingNewMarkers() {
        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                // This method will add a new marker to wherever the user long clicks on the Map.
                // The title of the marker will be set based on what is located at that location.
                // The Geocoder.getFromLocation() method gets the address and details of the location.

                // Find Details of location
                Geocoder geocoder;
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                assert addresses != null;
                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                // End - Find details of location

                // Add the new marker to the map
                MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
                mo.position(latLng);
                mo.title(knownName + ", " + address + ", " + city + ", " + state + ", " + country);
                mo.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(new Random().nextFloat() * 360));
                googleMap.addMarker(mo);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

I've then added this fragment to my MainActivity.

You will need to add some permissions to your manifest and also specify your google maps API key. The manifest file for this is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="YOUR_PACKAGE"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: What does the MainActivity.locationManager do here?

Comment: It gets the Location Service. `locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: This code is not working for me. My code gives me the map for first time but after resuming the map fragment it doesn't work. That's the problem.